# In-line string substitution in Java?

Tags: java, ruby, string, concatenation, processing

I'm doing some work in Processing, which is basically Java. I normally do only work in Ruby and I've gotten used to a lot of the fairly elegant and beautiful code conventions there.

If I have a string that I'd like to insert other strings into, what's the most beautiful way to do it in Java?

In Ruby, I do something like this generally (where each variable is a string):

```
p "The #{person_title} took a #{mode_of_transit} to the #{holiday_location} for a nice #{verb} in the #{noun}"
```

It would appear in Java that I need to manually concatenate them like this:

```
println("The " + personTitle + " took a " + modeOfTransit + " to the " holidayLocation + for a nice " + verb + " in the " + noun)
```

This just feels wrong to me. It works, but it just isn't smooth. Is there a way to do this in Java?

Comment: You can use String.format: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...) I just find that messy, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The closest would be something like:

```
 String s = String.format("The %s took a %s to the %s for a nice %s in the %s", personTitle, modeOfTransit, holidayLocation, verb, noun);
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method for building a formatted string, or [PrintStream.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) for formatting and printing directly. (`System.out` is a `PrintStream`.)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `System.out.format()` method to write formatted string to `System.out` or format a string using the static method `String.format.` For more details on formatting read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html) article.

```
System.out.format("The %s took a %s to the %s for a nice %s in the %s",
         personTitle, modeOfTransit, holidayLocation, verb, noun);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`System.out.printf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf) (same as `System.out.format`) and a [format string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) (`"%s"` is the format specifier for a string) to both make it look more fluid and also format your output the way you want.

There's also `String.format` that returns the formatted `String`, rather than having to print it (like `sprintf` in C).